# Referential integrity in a sharded database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, postgresql-9.3

How can referential integrity be maintained in a sharded database on the server-side if foreign keys no longer work?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. That's why you shouldn't do so until you have to.

Comment: By "manually" I assume you mean badly or incorrectly? Yes. If you're asking then you'll get it wrong. I would, amd I've been doing database-backed applications for years.

Comment: @paulkon In most "noSQL" databases I'm aware of it isn't *enforced* at all. The application attempts to maintain relationships and cope when they're broken/missing. But saying "how does noSQL do [x]" is a bit like saying "what engine oil type should I put in my car?" ... almost completely impossible to know without knowing *which car* because *they're all different* and *not all of them even have engine oil*.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think you misunderstood my comment. I'm aware that nosql does not maintain referential integrity of any sort and I was confirming if enforcing referential integrity on the app side would be as much of a pain when enforcing it in a sharded sql database.

Comment: As Richard stated, doing it manually usually ends up not quite perfect which is why I was hoping for an alternate solution in the answer.

Comment: @paulkon It sounds like you're looking for a clustered fully ACID database with things like cross-node RI then. Such DBs exist, but require fast low-latency links between the cluster nodes and don't tend to scale particularly wonderfully to large node counts.